# Sequelize- Not return promise after create an instarnce

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create new filter and print (console.log) the id of the object just created, but it doesn't enter to the .then function.
Here's the code:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var FilterModel = require('../models/filters');
var Filter = new FilterModel(Database, Sequelize);

Filter.create({ name: data.filter_name }).then(function(filter) {
  console.log( '***************************************' );
});
```

And the '**' not printed,but the entry is in the DB.

When i tried to do like this:

```
var filter = Filter.create({ name: data.filter_name })
```

And print 'filter' i've got the new instance with the created_at etc. but the id is NULL.

The id defined as:

```
id: {
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
  },
```

Please someone can help what's wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that Filter.create() returns a promise or at least a thenable object? If so the promise might have just returned rejected so you may try to add a second function to catch the result of the rejection.

Comment: Your `new FilterModel()` should return `Sequelize.define()` object

Comment: @TilekbekovYrysbek I already define it in the model.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, it's enter to the 'then' and print the console.

It bypass the 'then' go to the next lines and then back (after the promise finished), to the 'then' function.

I debug it and added console.log after

```
Filter.create({ name: data.filter_name }).then(function(filter) {
 console.log( '***************************************' );
});
console.log('after')
```

So now, it prints 'after'
and then print '******'

Thanks anyway.

Comment: How is this code different to what's in your questions?